# internal static IP address configuration from router

Tags: networking, router, ip, dhcp, webserver

How do I reserve an IP address for `tleilax` and ensure that `tleilax` only gets that reserved address?  The `tleilax` box uses DHCP.

When I look at attached devices, I see:

```
Attached Devices

Wired Devices
#   IP Address  MAC Address     Device Name
1   192.168.1.6 00:13:20:AC:13:B0   TLEILAX
2   192.168.1.2 50:E5:49:C2:C8:05   DOGE


Wireless Devices
#   IP Address  MAC Address     Device Name
1   ----    C4:43:8F:E4:72:36   <Unknown>
```

How can I ensure that `tleilax` always gets assigned the same IP address?  The `tleilax` box uses **DHCP**, but the router—[a Netgear Wireless-N 150 Router WNR1000v2](http://documentation.netgear.com/wnr1000v2/enu/202-10546-01/index.htm)—should always give it the same IP address.

It also happens that `tleilax`, has the [FQDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name) of `tleilax.bounceme.net` and so that domain should be registered in the [router](http://documentation.netgear.com/wnr1000v2/enu/202-10546-01/index.htm) as well so that anyone on the LAN (me) can navigate to `http://tleilax.bounceme.net/` and the router will direct to `tleilax` accordingly.

I prefer to do this configuration on the [router](http://documentation.netgear.com/wnr1000v2/enu/202-10546-01/index.htm), so that `tleilax` can use **DHCP**, but don't quite know where to start with the [router](http://documentation.netgear.com/wnr1000v2/enu/202-10546-01/index.htm).

Comment: It always was in the question; the "router" is clickable in the question.  I figured that was clear; pardon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### How can I ensure that tleilax always gets assigned the same IP address?

Use Address Reservation.

---

> To configure LAN IP settings, select LAN Setup under Advanced in the
>   main menu. The LAN Setup screen displays:
>
> [image]

...

> **Using Address Reservation**
>
> When you specify a reserved IP address for a computer on the LAN, that
>   computer always receives the same IP address each time it accesses the
>   router’s DHCP server. Reserved IP addresses should be assigned to
>   computers or servers that require permanent IP settings.
>
> [image]
>
> To reserve an IP address:
>
> 1. Click Add
> 2. In the IP Address field, enter the IP address to assign to the computer or server. (Choose an IP address from the router’s LAN
>      subnet, such as 192.168.1.x.)
> 3. Enter the MAC address of the computer or server.
>
> If the computer is already present on your network, you can copy its
>   MAC address from the Attached Devices screen and paste it here.
>
> 4. Click Apply to enter the reserved address into the table.
>
> Note:
>
> The reserved address is not assigned until the next time the computer
>   contacts the router’s DHCP server. Reboot the computer or access its
>   IP configuration and force a DHCP release and renew.

Source [Wireless-N 150 Router WNR1000v2 User Manual](http://documentation.netgear.com/wnr1000v2/enu/202-10546-01/usermanual.pdf):